# Images on nav bar before each link

Tags: image, navbar

Right, so I have made a navigation bar and I want to add images before each link, I know I can use a.header:before but I need different images for each link, a house for home, spanner for spec and so on. What is the simplest way of doing this? Is there a way without creating a div for each one and styling them individually?

For a preview of the page so far with the nav - http://zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com/

One more thing - here is part of the css:

```
#header-nav {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 80px; height: 8.0rem;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}

.header-nav-center {
    height: 80px; height: 8.0rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 500px; width: 50.0rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.header-nav-center ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.header-nav-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 35px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}

a.header {
    line-height: 80px; line-height: 8.0rem;
    font-size: 17px; font-size: 1.7rem;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="header-nav">
      <div id="hr-nav-top-container">
        <hr class="nav" />
      </div>
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div class="header-nav-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="header" href="#features">Features</a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="header" href="#specification">Specification</a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="header" href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="pre-order"></div>
      <div id="hr-nav-bottom-container">
        <hr class="nav" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I add something like:

```
a.header.home:before {
    background: url('../images/home-logo.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Not that exactly but something like it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make ids for each link and add the ids to the desired link img

Comment: That's one thing I thought off but was just curious if there was a way which didn't require styling each link individually, I suppose there wouldn't be really.